# How to create a shortcut to a UWP app?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-store-app, uwp

I have a huge collection of images my windows machine cycles through for backgrounds, and sometimes I want to find out what a particular photo is of.

Going to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Themes` shows you the images on each display, named `Transcoded_000`, `Transcoded_001` et cetera; so they are without extension.
As such, you cant immediately open them nor teach explorer to associate them with an app/application.

So, what I thought to do was create a shortcut or batch file to `<application> "<path>/Transcoded_blah"` to call the app with the image as an argument.
However, since Win10 has done away with the old (.exe) photo viewer of Win7, and replaced it with the Win8+ app "Photos", I actually don't know how to call it.

UWPs dont hide in Program Files and there's no `Open file location` on its start menu item nor on its executable in Task Manager whilst it's running, so I don't know where to look to find it.
I imagine there's a way to launch these apps (probably PowerShell or [hopefully not] vbs), and I'm hoping they also accept arguments, but whenever I google it the results are for the other way around (invoking shell from UWP).

How do I invoke a Win10 app and pass it something?

Comment: Does this resource help: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/automate-launching-uwp-apps, or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45978066/how-to-launch-exe-app-with-parameter-uwp ??

Comment: it did make me google a little closer to where I'd want, but it doesn't accept arguments. [thanks to this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app#photos-app-uri-scheme), powershell: `start ms-photos:viewer?fileName=C:\Users\<redacted>\AppData\Roa
ming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\Transcoded_000.jpg`, it opens the right app, but the app doesn't open the image (I put the pull path, and copied the image out appending `.jpg` to eliminate confounding issues)

Comment: If photos is your default app you can just do  `start "c:\picture\pic1.jpg"` and it will launch in photos. Can't say I can offer anything useful on actually passing anything to the the viewer dll though.

Comment: @Narzard the files do not have an extension at all, that's the issue. I need some way to *tell* the system it is an image (without renaming/scripting, just in a shortcut). If you're just reading the comments, it's a `.jpg` there because we thought we found a way but it wasn't working, so I manually renamed to test if we were even on the right track; we weren't, it (calling viewer manually) didn't work even with the extension

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but is an okay workaround. Chrome is capable of reading the magic byte header and doesn't need a file extension. You can create a shortcut pointing to `powershell start chrome file://C:\Users\...\Transcoded_001` and it'll work